# Fourier transformation in C

Tags: c, fft

Hi I have such a task https://imageshack.com/i/ipaf9sg9j
I am trying to go in a direction but my compiler went mad (or simply I have done something wrong) (Visual Studio 2008 C++ express edition) and I don't know my errors. Could you point out the mistakes and point me in the right direction for 1. in the task.
This is my code so far (I know probably there are mistakes but I am just beginner)
https://imageshack.com/i/eyDnQnr6p

Comment: you can upload the image here, as well as the code, and you should, the links are not loading, so please click [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27965060/edit) and add your image and code to the question.

Comment: You should embed your code directly in your post see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I can't upload images because I am a new user. https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1725x969q90/673/af9sg9.jpg it is the task
and the code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{

 int func (double x[], int n);
 int N,i,t,n,m;
 double f;
 printf("input N\n");
 scanf(" %d",&N);
 printf("f=%lf\n",f);
 printf("t=%lf\n",t);

 double PI= 4.0*atan(1.0);

 for(i=1; i<=N; i+2);
 {
  for(t=0; t<=n; t++);
  {
  srand(time(NULL));
  double f = rand();

  x[t]=(4/PI)*((1/i)*sin(2*i*PI*f*t));
  x[t]>-10||x<10;
 }
 }
    
 
}

Comment: Have you checked my link ?

Answer (score 1):

1. You must define `x` as `double`.
   line 7 from the beginning of main, change `double f;` into `double f,x`;
2. You must add include to get the time method defined.

   #include "time.h"

Comment: You should also put your declaration *int func(double x[], int n);* outside the main() function.

Comment: That would be `<time.h>` for a Standard C header.

Comment: @rubenvb No, they don't, if there's a time.h somewhere else in the search path, it might pick up the wrong one. The <time.h> form makes sure you always get the Standard C version.

Comment: @Jens Well, yes, but naming your header like a standard C header is also bad. Technically speaking, both forms are implementation defined anyways. And if you aren't shooting yourself in the foot, both work.